# CSLA FieldManager.updatechildren(this) vs FieldManager.updatechildren

Tags: csla

I am new to CSLA and i am trying to understand the difference between FieldManager.updatechildren(this) vs FieldManager.updatechildren.
When is it appropriate to use either one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the answer to my question. Use FieldManager.UpdateChildren(this) when updating a certain child with certain parameters. All other cases we use FieldManager.UpdateChildren